# Why isn't the scalar field a covector?

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, vectors

A one-form (or covector) maps a vector space to its field of scalars.
A scalar field maps any position of spacetime into a scalar.

Given that the 4-position is a vector, can we say that the map of the scalar field is a one-form? If not, what's up with the given definitions?

Comment: Spacetime is a manifold, and only sometimes accidentally a vector space.

Comment: But in QFT we deal with Minkowski, which is always a vector space

Comment: Even then, a covector is a *linear* map on vectors, and no one requires a scalar field to be linear. I'm not really sure how the field is supposed to be a 1-form here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind i guess this is the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the position is not a 4-vector.

Let me explain.

You start with a differentiable manifold $\mathcal{M}$ which does not have a structure of a vector space: on a manifold no vectors exist.
Position is just a point living in that manifold: $p = (x_1, x_2, ... ,x_n)$
This is not a vector: you can't sum points on a manifold, neither multiply them with a scalar.

To do so, you need a vector space, an additional structure which is added to the manifold: a vector bundle.

Such structure assigns a vector space to EACH point on the manifold.

A "position vector" in such a space, only if the vector space has the same dimension as the manifold, can be interpreted as a separation vector rather than a position vector.

Now to scalar fields.

Scalar fields are functions from the manifold points to scalars, so they Map points to numbers. Vectors are not present clearly there.

1-forms are linear functions on vectors in the vector bundle so fixed a point on the manifold they do not care about the manifold, only about vectors.

You can relate the scalar field on the manifold to 1-forms via the differential operator:

$$d: \phi \rightarrow d\phi$$

$d\phi$ is then a 1-form which you can apply to vectors, specially the separation vectors defined above.

Comment: but then my question could simply be re-worded substituting $X^{μ}$ to "4-position"; in fact, in QFT, where the manifold is flat (so globally is the same as locally, where vector spaces are defined) the fields are all functions of $X^{μ}$, and i guess we all agree that  $X^{μ}$ is a vector

Comment: In minkowsky you have the same exact structure. $X^\mu$ is not a position on the manifold but a vector, the separation vector from the origin. Since Minkowsky is flat you can overlap the manifold and the vector bundle. This makes possible to NUMERICALLY identify the separation with a position. But this DO NOT make a position a vector quantity, since a coordinate point has no direction nor magnitude. In QFT fields are functions of position $x$, not $X^\mu$. QF theoriests use $X^\mu$ because they dont care about geometry, since NUMERICALLY you can swap the coordinates for the vector components.

Comment: Just think about this: vectors have directions and magnitudes, positions only have components. Fields only depends on the latter, not the former.

Comment: But then the question would just shift to "is the scalar field (defined on every point  in flat spacetime) also a set of covectors defined on the vector space *associated with* every point  in flat spacetime?"

Comment: Clearly no, first: covectors MUST be linear, scalar fields dont. Second: how could you extract a set of covectors from an expression like $F(x_1, x_2) = ln(x_1)\sqrt{x_2/x_1}$?

Comment: You could find useful the following notion: you can assign to a pair of vector+covector fields $\vec{v}(x) , \alpha(x)$ a scalar field as: $\phi(x) = g^i_j(x) \alpha_i(x)v^j(x)$ but you cannot write every scalar field as a covector set as said previously

Comment: but then could i say the other way around? aka that "the set of covectors defined on the vector space associated with every point  in flat spacetime is an example of scalar field (defined on every point  in flat spacetime)" ? Specifically, a *linear* example

Comment: Also consider that scalar fields in a point do not change if you change a basis, since they only depend on the point, but covectors do change, since they have components which $F(x)$ cleary has not

Comment: @TrentKent6 define for me "set of covectors". If you mean the components of a covector field then yes, you can say that such components, applied to a certain vector field, do indeed form a scalar field. But that is a very very very specific example of scalar fields

Comment: that's all i wanted to know as of now. but now let's talk about this covector field (the very specific example of scalar field), and consider this: let's apply a Lorentz transformation as we commonly do in QFT. How would this field change? would it be invariant (since it's a "very specific example of scalar field") or would it change covariantly (since it's a "covector field")?

Comment: It's invariant since what is the specific scalar field is the contraction of the covector with a covector. It want this to be clear: the specific scalar field is not a covector, it's a covector APPLIED TO a vector

Comment: A scalar field is not a covector field. A covector field applied to a vector field is a very specific scalar field

Comment: can you elaborate on "you can say that such components, applied to a certain vector field, do indeed form a scalar field. But that is a very specific example of scalar fields" of your previous comment, to help me understand better your point?

Comment: A covector field has components, like vectors. A covector when applied to a vector couples through the natural isomorphism. Let $\alpha$ be a covector and $v$ a vector. Since both depend on the spacetime points, the contraction $\alpha(x)[v(x)]$ is a scalar field. The quantity alone $\alpha(x)[\cdot ]$ is not a scalar field, is a covector field